# Getting all links from page, receiving javascript.void() error?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get all the links from this page to the incident reports, in a csv format. However, as they don't seem to be "real links" (if you open in new tab then you receive an "about:blank" error). They do have their own links - visible in inspect element. I'm pretty confused. I did find some code online to do this, but just got "Javascript.void()" as every link.

Surely there must be a way to do this?

https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/accidents/us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load all the links into a DataFrame and save it to CSV, you can use this example:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc_us.php?'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
r = re.compile(r"window\.open\('(.*?)'")

data = []
for link in soup.select('a[onclick*="window"]'):
    data.append({'text':link.get_text(strip=True),
        'link':r.search(link['onclick']).group(1)})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                                 text                                               link
0                 Mount Emmons, west of Crested Butte  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
1     Point 12885 near Red Peak, west of Silverthorne  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
2                    Austin Canyon, Snake River Range  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
3            Taylor Mountain, northwest of Teton Pass  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
4                               North of Skyline Peak  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
..                                                ...                                                ...
238  Battle Mountain - outside Vail Mountain ski area  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
239            Scotch Bonnet Mountain, near Lulu Pass  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
240                                 Near Paulina Peak  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
241                         Rock Lake, Cascade, Idaho  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...
242     Hyalite Drainage, northern Gallatins, Bozeman  https://www.avalanche.state.co.us/caic/acc/acc...

[243 rows x 2 columns]
```

And saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the onclick property of this link and get "real" address from them.